# Eclipse plug-in creates new workspace everytime when its executed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to work on an existing project which is stored in workspace say wrkspc1.
The plug-in by default creates a new empty workspace say wrkspc2. In order to work on existing project I moved my project into wrkspc2 as the root path of workspace cannot be modified. Now each time I am executing the plug-in, it is creating a workspace on system (wrkspc2). Due to this the project that I had placed in the workspace gets deleted.

Is there any way by which I can work on existing project by any means?

**Aim:**

My project is located at suppose path : C:/User/XYX/wrkspc2

Step 1: I want to open this workspace

Step 2: An existing project within the workspace - say project2

Step 3: Build the project

**Code:**

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
```

//The statement when executed creates en empty workspace for each execution

Comment: What do you have in the Run Configuration for the Location?

Comment: As I am new to Plug-in, where can i find run configuration file?

Comment: `Run` menu, `Run Configurations`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. Now wherever `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();` is getting called, its not creating a new folder on system.  But the new problem is that - I have placed my project in that folder and executing the below code: `workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
  root = workspace.getRoot();
  System.out.println("Root path: "+root.getLocation()); 
  
  IProject[] projectList = root.getProjects();
  System.out.println("Total projects: "+projectList.length);` **Result** Total projects: 0
Even though the project exist within the workspace, it is not locating it.

Comment: You may need to call `root.refreshLocal` to get the workspace to recognize the project.

Comment: Tried:
`root = workspace.getRoot();
progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
root.refreshLocal(IResource.ROOT, progressMonitor);`

Still get result as 0

Comment: Should be `IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE`.  How did you create this project? It must have the correct contents (such as a .project file) to be recognized.

Comment: Thanks Greg. It worked. Only mistake I did is - Copy pasted the project in workspace folder but in eclipse I did not import it. Once that is done, it is now identifying the project. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the path in Run Configuration menu, it worked. Now it does not create workspace but instead point to one which is given in Run Configuration